Finite fiber of morphism
I'm checking the proof of Lemma 4.1.5 in this notes, and I'll briefly summerize the proof here.
With the assumption, one could construct a morphism $\pi$:
$$
[x_0:\cdots:x_n]\mapsto[y_0:\cdots:y_n]:=[x_0^d:\cdots:x_{n-1}^d,f]
$$
By closedness of the morphism and projective Nullstellensatz, one gets an equation
$$
y_n^D=g_1(y_0:\cdots:y_n)y_1+\cdots+g_{n-1}(y_0:\cdots:y_n)y_{n-1}
$$
in the projective ring of $\pi(X)$. By subsituting back, one gets the equation
$$
f^D+a_{D-1}f^{D-1}+\cdots+a_0=0
$$
in the coordinate ring of $X$.
It seems that we cannot control $g_i$'s, so my questions are:

Why are $a_i$ homogeneous polynomials?
Why $D$ is the largest power of $f$?


You summarized the proof but not what you're trying to prove, so potential askers still have to click the link and go find it. Please make your post self-contained - in addition to the obvious benefits of protecting against link rot, this will increase the likelihood you'll receive an answer :)
